# Draw rectangles along a circle using html5, css3 and js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to draw 32 rectangles along a circle using html5, css3 and js. 
You can see my goal with this image:

[image: myGoal]
.

My designed solution was to create "a for" in js that would generate 32 rectangles each time increasing rotation, coordinates and z-index. I tried but it is too intricate.

Please help me.

Comment: How about drawing a circle, and then subtracting out the inner area with another circle, and breaking the resultant ring into pieces with line segments? Also, is SVG an option? If so: http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: oh, and if you use actual rectangles it'll look wrong - you need to use partial arcs so that the inner and outer edges are curved instead of straight, and the gaps between don't converge more than they should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a new version, updated to show the OP's requirement to have an actual DOM element for each rectangle, and not a single canvas:

```
var n = 32;

for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    var r = 360 * i / n;
    var s = 'translate(200px,200px) rotate(' + r + 'deg) translate(0px, -180px)';

    d.setAttribute('class', 'box');
    d.setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform:' + s);

    var t = document.createTextNode(i);
    d.appendChild(t);

    document.body.appendChild(d);
}​
```

working demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/CFAyf/ which contains some additional (and necessary) CSS

NB: you'll need to use browser detection to set the right `-transform` style attribute.  The sample shown is correct for Chrome and Safari.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are great! i have learned so much from you :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

This creates a canvas like your picture - tune the variables as desired:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('c');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var w = canvas.width;
var h = canvas.height;

var r1 = Math.min(w, h) * 0.4;    // outer radius
var r0 = r1 - 40;                 // inner radius

var n = 32;                       // number of blocks

var theta = 2 * Math.PI / n;
var phi = theta * 0.45;           // relative half-block width

ctx.save();
ctx.fillStyle = '#c0c0c0';
ctx.translate(w / 2, h / 2);      // move to center of circle

for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, r0, -phi, phi);
    ctx.arc(0, 0, r1, phi, -phi, true);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.rotate(theta);            // rotate the coordinates by one block
}

ctx.restore();
​
```

working sample at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/qxZ5b/

**EDIT** this was incorrect (the OP wanted separate DOM elements, not a canvas) but is left here for reference.  See my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10819173/6782) for a DOM-based method.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers! I forgot an important detail. Rectangles must be elements that can handle html as div or li because I go to js then interact with their properties such as changing the color.

Comment: @RiccardoGiacomini yeah, that's why I asked whether you needed a canvas or not...

Comment: @Alnitak have you found some solution or a way to do where i can work on

Comment: @RiccardoGiacomini yeah, see second answer.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't perfect, but it gets something very similar...

```
div {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 10px dotted #E5E5E5;
   border-radius: 200px;    
}​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SVZYG/).

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with only CSS. Did it for another project and it works for ie9+ and all modern browsers.

This creates a circle with seperate DOM elements, clickable and what not.

```
<div class="wrapper" id="wrapper">
             <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class=""></span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" ><span class=""></span></a></li>
             </ul>
            <div class="content"><p id="timeFirst"></p><br /><p>till</p><br /><p class="timeLast"></p></div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

and the css

```
.csstransforms .wrapper {
      display: block;
      font-size:1em;
      width: 10em;
          height: 10em;
          border-radius: 50%; 
          position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: 0 auto;
      z-index: 99;
 }
.csstransforms .wrapper li
{
    list-style: none;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    transform-origin: 100% 100%;
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -10em;
    margin-left: -10em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white; 
}
.csstransforms .wrapper li a
{
    display: block;
    width: 10.5em;
    height: 10.5em;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    bottom: -7.5em;
    right: -7.5em;
    background-color: #D9D9D9; 
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-60deg) rotate(-90deg) scale(2);
    -moz-transform: skew(-60deg) rotate(-90deg) scale(2);
    -ms-transform: skew(-60deg) rotate(-90deg) scale(2);
    -o-transform: skew(-60deg) rotate(-90deg) scale(2);
    transform: skew(-60deg) rotate(-90deg) scale(2);
}
.wrapper .content
{   
    position: absolute;
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    top:10%;
    left:10%;
    z-index: 25;
}
.csstransforms .wrapper li a:hover,
.csstransforms .wrapper li a:focus,
.csstransforms .wrapper li a:active
{
    background-color: #919191;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(9) a
{
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    cursor: default;

}
.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(9) a:hover,
.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(9) a:focus,
.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(9) a:active
{
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    cursor: default;

}
.active /*Later for use with JS */
{
    background-color:#32ADCF;
}
.csstransforms .wrapper li:first-child {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(30deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(30deg) skew(60deg);

}

.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(60deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(60deg) skew(60deg);

}

.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(90deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg) skew(60deg);
}
.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(120deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(120deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(120deg) skew(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(120deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(120deg) skew(60deg);
}
.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(5) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(150deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg) skew(60deg);
}

.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(6) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(180deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg) skew(60deg);
}
.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(7) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(210deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(210deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(210deg) skew(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(210deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(210deg) skew(60deg);
}
.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(8) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(240deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(240deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(240deg) skew(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(240deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(240deg) skew(60deg);
}
.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(9) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg) skew(60deg);
}
.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(10) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(300deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(300deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(300deg) skew(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(300deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(300deg) skew(60deg);
}
.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(11) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(330deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(330deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(330deg) skew(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(330deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(330deg) skew(60deg);
}
.csstransforms .wrapper li:nth-child(12) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) skew(60deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) skew(60deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) skew(60deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg) skew(60deg);
  transform: rotate(360deg) skew(60deg);
   z-index:-1; /* Last element index set to minus to fix a bug in IE9+ */

}
```

And the formula for rotating for you using 32 rectangles would be 360/32 = 11.25 as a central angle. Then you need to skew the rectangles to fit your central angle using the formula 90 - x( where X is your central angle) so 78,75. If you want content inside your rectangles you need to skew them back with the oposite value of that you used to skew the list items. Rotate back the content of the list items using the formula 90 -(x/2) where x is central angle. so for you it would be 90 -(11,25/2) = 84.4

***Edited***

Added a working JS fiddle so people can see it works. http://jsfiddle.net/AaJ94/